How to see if an element is getting oxidised or reduced?
For example, in $\ce{H2 + Cl2 -> 2 HCl}$, how do we find the oxidation numbers of $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{Cl2}$ and of $\ce{H}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ in $\ce{HCl}$?

You need to look at the electronegativity

how do i do that?

Be careful to use proper capitalization of element symbols.

You have free reactants $\ce{H2 and Cl2}$ so their Oxidation state is 0.
Hydrogen has a positive oxidation state when bonded to nonmetals, and the sum of the oxidation states in a compound without charge always adds up to 0.
Now, we can consider your product $\ce{HCl}$
So H has a oxidation state of +1 whereas Cl has an oxidation state of -1. (based on the no of electrons that are involved in bond formation)
(-1) + 1 = 0. (Showing that sum of oxidation states = 0)
An increase in oxidation number is oxidation and a decrease is reduction i.e. the increase or decrease in comparison to the original oxidation states in the reactant side
so in this case, H undergoes oxidation and Cl undergoes reduction.
However, your reaction is pretty simple so you can simply say that H is oxidised due to addition of an electronegative element (Cl) and Cl is reduced due to addition of Hydrogen.

Oxidation means addition of oxygen and reduction of hydrogen to a compound. Whereas Reduction means addition of Hydrogen and removal of oxygen. Redox reactions are basically both oxidation and reduction happening simultaneously.

The method you suggest is essentially useless for many kinds of reactions.
